# In Python, get the output of system command as a string

Tags: python, shell, command-line

In python I can run some system command using os or subprocess. The problem is that I can't get the output as a string. For example:

```
>>> tmp = os.system("ls")
file1 file2
>>> tmp
0
```

I have an older version of subprocess that doesn't have the function `check_out`, and I would prefer a solution that doesn't require to update that module since my code will run on a server I don't have full admin rights.

Comment: you need `popen` PIPE, system probably returns process termination status

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I tried it as well but couldn't make it work. Can you show an example?

Comment: @S4M Read: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use [`os.popen()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen):

```
tmp = os.popen("ls").read()
```

The newer way (> python 2.6) to do this is to use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements):

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
tmp = proc.stdout.read()
```

Comment: An example using subprocess will be helpful :)

Comment: Added an example with subprocess

Comment: tmp = os.popen("ls").read()  is fine. I have python 2.6.

Comment: why subprocess may be better?