# how to store return value and NOT command call status using python script?

Tags: python, shell, hadoop

I am trying to test if a path exist in hadoop using python script.

`hdfs dfs -test -e /path/to/file`

The above will return 0 if path exists, 1 if path doesn't exist. Below is my python script:

```
if subprocess.call("hdfs dfs -test -e /path/to/file", shell = True) == 0:
    # do something
```

The above code it's not working, subprocess is always 0 b/c it's checking the command status not the returned value. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243020/in-python-get-the-output-of-system-command-as-a-string), but didn't seem to work. I also tried storing the return value of echo`result = subprocess.call("echo $?", shell = True)`, also didn't work.

Below is my full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

HDFS = "hdfs dfs "

def run_commands(func, path):
    subprocess.call(HDFS + func + path, shell = True)

def path_exist(path):
    return True if run_commands("-test -e ", path) == 0 else False

path_exist("/path/to/file")
```

Comment: I tried your code, and `subprocess.call` returned `1` when I put in a path that did not exist in HDFS.  What isn't working for you?

Comment: @MattD I'm not sure why it's not working. the `if` statement above always equates to 0, even when the path doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `run_commands` to

```
def run_commands(func, path):
    return subprocess.call(HDFS + func + path, shell = True)
```

`run_commands` is not automatically returning the return code from `subprocess.call`.  It will return `None`.  (Tested in python 2.6.6).

Because of that, `if run_commands("-test -e ", path) == 0` will not be true.