# Unable to store terminal output of subprocess with python

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

My code has two potential outcomes in the terminal: `Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Permission denied` and `Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Host is down`. I need to store either result as a string in a variable, but everything I've tried has failed. This is the code that I thought would do it:

```
from subprocess import check_output

out = check_output(["sudo", "rfcomm", "connect", "0", "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF", "10"])
print "output: %s" % out
```

Instead I get nothing:

```
user:~/home $./foo.py
Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Permission denied
output:
```

Another attempt:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["sudo rfcom connect 0 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF 10"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
print "output: %s" % out, err
```

This at least gives me something when I print. Unfortunately it's "None" telling me there is no error and not the actual output:

```
user:~/home $./foo.py
Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Permission denied
output:  None
```

I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243020/in-python-get-the-output-of-system-command-as-a-string) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514751/pipe-subprocess-standard-output-to-a-variable) and probably a couple others. I'm sure I'm missing a piece of critical knowledge somewhere. Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Did you try adding: `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rfcomm` is apparently writing its output to standard error, yet you are only capturing standard output.  To capture both, include `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` in the call to `check_output`:

```
subprocess.check_output(["sudo", "rfcomm", "connect", "0", "AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF", "10"],
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Thought I tried that the right way earlier but I guess not.

Comment: thanks for this answer, helped me tooooo.